# Apache mod_proxy to another server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, proxy, load-balancing, ruby-on-rails

I am using the proxy_balancer in Apache2 to proxy requests to a Rails application to my rails server on the port the application is running on. This is how its set up...

**Rails Server**
Mongrel running on port 8000, when accessing the url directly to http://rails_server:8000 the site loads fine

**Apache Server**
Conf file for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAlias application.myserver.com

    <Proxy balancer://application_cluster>
            Allow from localhost
            BalancerMember http://ip.to.server:8000 retry=10
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / balancer://application_cluster
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I am having is going to http://rails_server:8000 works fine, but going to http://application.myserver.com Loads the right content, but is displaying all the HTML as text and not rendering it as html

Comment: I miss a ProxyPassReverse / balancer://application_cluster directive. Also, what's the output of curl -I http://application.myserver.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

> ProxyPassReverse / balancer://application_cluster

like Inigo said in his comment. Just below ProxyPass.

(wow just realized I'm over a year late with this post, "unanswered question" it is but I doubt the author ever comes back)

Answer (score 0):

I would check the content type returned by the URLs in question.  It sounds like one is passing "text/html" and the other "text/plain" . . . perhaps in your proxy configuration you need to frob some content-type setting.

-d

Comment: It is giving me a content type of text/plain, but when I use this same method to proxy to Mongrel instances running on the same machine as Apache things work fine, why would this be happening just because it is coming from a different server?

Comment: If I set the `DefaultType` directive in the conf file it shows the html file, but every other file such as css files get the text/html content type. Why is this proxy not detecting the proper content type for the files?

Comment: Honestly, I have no experience with this.  Just taking a stab that Apache is messing with the content-type.  Hopefully someone has a proper solution.  Good luck!